# How to show output of command in stdout/stderr while also saving the output into a variable in Go?

Tags: go, io, pipe, stdout, stderr

I think I'm on the right track but my solution just hangs and doesn't print anything to screen, what am I doing wrong here?

```
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = w
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    tstdout := io.TeeReader(r, os.Stdout)
    tstderr := io.TeeReader(r, os.Stderr)
    io.Copy(&stdout, tstdout)
    io.Copy(&stderr, tstderr)

    err := cmd.Run()

    res := processResult{
        stderr.String(),
        stdout.Bytes(),
    }
```

Comment: You call `io.Copy` without spinning it off into a goroutine. This will read from the tee-reader's `tstdout` until the tee-reader returns EOF. The tee-reader reads from `r`, the read end of the pipe. The write end is currently open, and there are no bytes to read, so `io.Copy` waits for `treader`'s data (or EOF). Nothing else is providing any data, so `io.Copy` continues to wait, as does the tee reader, and both will keep doing so forever or until some other event terminates the program—nobody else has `r` so no one is writing on it yet.

Comment: If you spin off both `io.Copy` calls as new goroutines, you'll get much better results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read from the reader returned from "io.TeeReader" asynchronously. Here's an example that does something similar to what I think you're trying to do.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    prout, pwout := io.Pipe()
    prerr, pwerr := io.Pipe()

    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "echo this is stdout; echo 1>&2 this is stderr")
    cmd.Stdout = pwout
    cmd.Stderr = pwerr

    tout := io.TeeReader(prout, os.Stdout)
    terr := io.TeeReader(prerr, os.Stderr)

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var bout, berr bytes.Buffer

    go func() {
        if _, err := io.Copy(&bout, tout); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        if _, err := io.Copy(&berr, terr); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("buffered out %s", bout.String())
    fmt.Printf("buffered err %s", berr.String())
}
```

The output is:

```
this is stdout
this is stderr
buffered out this is stdout
buffered err this is stderr
```

And the program should run to completion and exit successfully.